# Are there any specific documents to carry when travelling from Bangalore to Hong Kong via Bangkok without visa?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, visas-on-arrival, hong-kong, bangalore

I am going on a short tour from Bangalore to Hong Kong and my flights are with Thai Airways which go via Bangkok. Hong Kong provides visa on arrival for Indian citizens, and so does Thailand even though there is no requirement for me to get a visa there as the connection time is less than two hours.

So, essentially I need to travel without any visa - only flight tickets + hotel booking. My new passport issued in 2012 has a blank second page - so it is a ECNR passport. The older one issued in 2002 said "ECR required except for travel to Pakistan, Bangladesh, etc....". I will also be travelling with my wife who a ECNR passport issued in 2012.

My question is - Are there any documents to carry while travelling? Is there any reason why the immigration officer in Bangalore can ask for additional documents before allowing us to pass?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can tell reading on the embassies websites there is no reason for them to stop you at the airport at either destination. With the switch in BKK (Bangkok) I believe you will not enter customs and your luggage is automatically forwarded.

The people at Bangalore have the option of stopping you if they think you will be refused entry to your destination. If your passport is enough to get you a Visa On Arrival then there is no reason for them to refuse you the flight. Also there is a chance Hong Kong would refuse you if you can not prove your continued itinerary, for that reason there is a chance they will stop you at Bangalore on the same grounds. A return ticket fixes this, or proof of continued traveling to other destination.

So bring the usual stuff, your passport and (return) tickets.

Good luck!